# Laravel, how to change array key permanently?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

Tried using array_values but it only temporary.

**controller**

```
foreach($rows as $key => $value)
{
  array_values($value);
  //dd shows the key changes to [0], [1], [2] and so on
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean permanently? Do you want the array to be saved? If so you'll need to store the data in a DB.

Comment: if i pass it to view by compact($rows); and use it in view, it change to normal

Comment: What are the keys in your current array? And what do you want them setting to?

Comment: the current one is shown in the picture above, I wanted to change $value['how'] to numeric like this $value['0']......so it become 0=>144, 1=>1, 2=>2 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
$rows = array_map(function($v){return array_values($v);}, $rows);
```

Comment: oh nice...pretty neat

Comment: more beautiful, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$new = [];
foreach($rows as $key => $value)
{
  array_values($value);
  $sub = [];
  foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
    $subKey = $key;
    $sub[$key] = $subValue;
  }
  $new[$key] = $sub;
  //dd shows the key changes to [0], [1], [2] and so on
}
```

Then return `$new` instead of `$rows`.

Comment: hmm...is there alternative beside this? or is there an eloquent way of doing this?

Comment: Not to change array keys. The code could be made much cleaner but I'm in work at the minute so don't have the time. You could use the above as a base and clean it up a bit and then edit the answer maybe?

Comment: ok i will use this first while waiting for the cleaner version

Comment: Cool, ETA: 7:30pm GMT

Comment: Guys, this is Laravel and the solution is supposed to be simple. I suggest you seeking Laravel Collection section. And remember some methods there will not alter original collection. Convert your array into a collection and benefit the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using laravel you can also do:

```
$rows = collect($rows)->map(function ($value) {
    return Arr::accessible($value)?collect($value)->values()->all():$value;
})->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the associative array to an indexed array, do this:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: No need to complicate things.

Comment: does not change anything

Comment: @benineeeerrrr It actually does EXACTLY what you wanted. See here: https://code.sololearn.com/wF6d755yf5gG